# How can I access last created sub folder and its files in google drive using google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to access the last created subfolder from a parent folder and subfolder's files but i'm failing to do so. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

I'm trying to get files of the last created folder but it gives me an error.

```
function myFunction() {
  // set the folder to pull folder names from
var parentid = "19mrz1uwYVCnmW1XZJYq3";
var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentid);
var parentfolder= parent.getfolders();
var folders = parentfolder.getLastupdated();
  var dd = folders.getfiles();
}
```

I need to excess the last created subfolder and work on it's content to copy somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the newest folder with the JS function [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the Apps Script method [getDateCreated()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getdatecreated).

### Sample:

```
function myFunction() {

var parentid = "19mrz1uwYVCnmW1XZJYq3";
var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentid);
var parentfolder= parent.getFolders();
  var array=[];
  var arrayFolders=[];
  while (parentfolder.hasNext()) {
  var folders = parentfolder.next();
    array.push(folders.getDateCreated());
    arrayFolders.push(folders.getId());
  } 
  var date=array.reduce(function (a, b) { 
    return a > b ? a : b; 
  }); 
  var index=array.indexOf(date);
  var newestFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(arrayFolders[index]);
  var myFiles=newestFolder.getFiles();
}
```

Comment: ```var date=array.reduce(function (a, b) { 
    return a > b ? a : b; 
  }); ``` . Can you please explain me a bit how it works as I'm new to google-apps-script and because I also want to extract another folder's subfolder contents and then compare them both to copy contents.

Comment: Basically, the function loops through all dates comparing them pairwise and keeping the bigger one for further comparison - until finally the whole array has been reduced to one element - the one with the biggest value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce This links provides a detailed description of the method, including all parameters. `?:` is a ternary operator, in this case it means: if `a>b` return `a`, otherwise return `b`. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/javascript-operators